# SQL Server stored procedure taking a very long time on first run

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, timeout

I am having an issue with a timeout error I am getting within a c# program we use for rental agreements. This same procedure has worked for years, yet was slowing down over time. I am now getting a timeout error within the software upon trying to run the stored procedure. I have determined that is is server based and not code based because running the same UPDATE statement within SSMS causes it to have the same downtime.

**Some quick details**

- The issue resolves itself after the first or second run of the statement.
- The table only contains 210k rows.
- It is a SQL Server 2016 Express database running on Windows Server 2012.
- I'll include a screenshot of the statement taking 1:42.

[image]

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
 @SaleNumber bigint,
 @GuestNumber bigint,
 @PassNumber bigint,
 @FirstName nvarchar(50),
 @LastName nvarchar(50),
 @Zip nvarchar(50),
 @Email nvarchar(50),
 @Address nvarchar(50),
 @City nvarchar(50),
 @State nvarchar(50),
 @LiabilityChecked bit,
 @LiabilityID uniqueidentifier,
 @AcceptEmail bit,
 @Phone1 varchar(50)
AS

UPDATE Orders
SET FirstName = @FirstName, 
    LastName = @LastName, 
    Zip = @Zip, 
    Email = @Email, 
    Address1 = @Address, 
    City = @City, 
    State = @State, 
    LiabilityChecked = @LiabilityChecked, 
    LiabilityID = @LiabilityID, 
    AcceptEmail = @AcceptEmail, 
    Phone1 = @Phone1
WHERE  
    Sale_no = @SaleNumber 
    AND Pass_no = @PassNumber 
    AND Guest_no = @GuestNumber
```

**I have tried the following:**

- Removing the Entity Framework and hard coding the procedure. (in which I now believe to be a SQL server problem)
- Upping resources of the server even though the server is always under 40% usage.
- Creating an new Azure server (non express) and moving the database.
- Changing the `WHERE` clause to:

  ```
    DateRedeemed >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) 
    AND Sale_no = @SaleNumber
  ```

  I did this thinking the date window would be more efficient. I would not like to do this as a solution as this raises other coding problems.
- Verified no other procedure is locking the record.
- Ran `exec sp_updatestats` and `dbcc freeproccache`

**Edit 1:**
I am looking into indexing. Sorry I am a software guy and rarely do databasing. I am learning!
As to the

> there is no way an update based on a sale no given takes more than milliseconds unless something else has locks on the table.

I know this because once making the new database on azure I ran the select statement from SSMS without pointing anything else to it. So mine was the only call.

I will include the Execution plan below:

[image]

Comment: Try to run this query and share the execution plan, by doing this you might find a clue on why the query takes that long (maybe you are missing some indexes).

Comment: Let me guess - someone needs to learn what an Index is. "yet was slowing down over time." - is like the obvious clue. The more data, the slower (measurable) because table scans take longer. https://use-the-index-luke.com/ - there is no way an update based on a sale no given takes more than milliseconds unless something else has locks on the table.

Comment: And please provide query plan via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: I would suggest adding an index on your **Sale_no** column, this helps SQL Server find the row to update much more quickly. Without that index, it will have to search the entire 210k rows each time.

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan tells you that you need a [composite index](https://codingsight.com/easy-answers-to-5-vital-questions-about-composite-index-in-sql/) to optimize that query :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Orders_SalePassGuest ON 
       Orders (Sale_no, Pass_no, Guest_no)
```